# c++ data array with 0x00 character

Tags: c++, null, character, byte, winsock

I'm trying to send some data by socket with winsock. I am encountering the problem where my data (which is actually an array of char) may contain some zeros but the char 0x00 represents the null character and all the following characters are cut as it represents the terminating character. Does anyone have an idea on how I should solve this? What alternative could I use ?

What I want to do is to send bytes with winsock which might represents integers, char arrays or something else. The receiving part will take care of reading correctly, but this is not the concern of this post.

Comment: But the `send` family of functions don't use the NUL char as a ending mark. Instead they receive the number of characters to be sent. So your problem simply doesn't exist!

Comment: Yeah but the c++ char arrays will cut every thing following a null character!

Comment: No! That happens only when the char arrays are seen as _strings_. That depends on the function (see the individual doc.) For example, `strcpy/strcmp` uses the NUL char while `memcpy/memcmp` does not. And obviously, winsock `send` functions does not treat the byte buffer as a string.

Comment: Ok well let me see a few things with that ! Thx!

Comment: a problem could be if you use wchar_t (=TCHAR if compiled with unicode support) as character which uses two bytes for each character, wich may contain a 0 byte, especially for most latin characters.

Comment: @rodrigo when the array get passed to another function, every thing after the first null character is cut any way to work around that ?

Comment: @user1628526 - That depends on the function. For example, `printf("%s", a);` will cut the _string_ `a` on the first NUL, but `send(sock, a, 100, 0)` will send 100 bytes whatsoever. Note that the former treats `a` as a string while the latter treats `a` as a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be doing something like this :
`

char s[100];

//Do stuff with s

send(sock, s, strlen(s), flags);
`

strlen finds the lenght of a string by counting how many caracters are until it finds NULL (0).

Answer (score 0):

make the first two bytes in your data stream, be the length of the buffer you are sending.
then send that many bytes.

on the other end, read the two bytes, and then you know exactly how many bytes should be coming to you.

that will let you work around the issue.

also google network byte order.  there are some handy function calls, that make portability easy.